# from which address when I send some bitcoin in bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I send some bitcoins using bitcoin core, but not know which address sending from?

for example:
address A: 1 bitcoin
address B: 2 bitcoins

3 cases:

1. sending <=1 bitcoin
2. sending >1, <=2 bitcoins
3. sending >2, <=3 bitcoins

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, these answers are too complex. I just want simple answers of 3 cases(without fee). thanks anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bitcoin-core automatic coin selection](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103823/bitcoin-core-automatic-coin-selection)